# Need Help on Adding a Common Wire for Nest

Tags: hvac, furnace, thermostat, thermostat-c-wire, nest

I recently purchased a Nest thermostat. After couple weeks of usage, the Nest is constantly shut down due to low battery. I search online that adding a common wire is the go solution for this. However, I am not too familiar with electrical stuff, So I hope someone can help me on this. Unfortunately, I could not locate the circuit board, hopefully some of below pictures might be helpful.

Update:
I have reorganize the picture to match the number with scheme. Please let me know where I can connect my unused red wire to pick up the 24volt and used as common wire.

### 1. My thermostat

[image]

### 2. The box where I found my thermostat wires along with other wire bundles.

[image]

### 3. The switch found when I follow the red white blue green bundle going to the furnace.

[image]

### 4. Honeywell box.

[image]

### 5.

[image]

### 6. Transformer on the furnace.

[image]

### 7. Control

[image]

### 8. Scheme

[image]

Comment: You shouldn't have taken that cover off. All the thermostat wiring is low-voltage and is outside the box.  The high-voltage wiring (which is dangerous) is inside the box.  That's why the transformer is on the box lid, to keep the high voltage in and the low voltage out.

Comment: @Harper thanks for your comments. Without opening the lid, I would't be able to discover the unused red wire. How would you connect the unused red wire to make it a common wire for the thermostat?

Comment: The Nest runs on 24V, not 120V.  You have 120V wiring inside that junction box.  I turned up the brightness on that first photo... does that cable coming off the *outside* of the transformer, does that loop *back into* the inside of the junction box????  From the other photos, it appears it does not.  You need to follow *that* cable.   If it did loop back into the box, that would be illegal and dangerous.

Comment: Hi @Harper, there is a hole on the other side of box (blocked by the box in picture 2 and 3), seem like it's going to the second floor. Also, I think there is another transformer (I will take picture) on the furnace as well, where it has a black and white wires attached to it.

Comment: Another transformer!  That and what you said settles it, all your thermostat wiring is outside that box.  Follow the wires which are coming off those 2 transformers, good chance one of them is a doorbell and the  other for furnace controls.

Comment: @Harper, I have include the inside of the second transformer, there are two wires red and white shown up, which I believe it's the same red and white that is coming out the junction box through the black pipe. Does that mean that I can twist the unused red wire with the bundle that has yellow cap with two red wires (picture 2)? One of the red wire is the wire that goes to the second transformer (picture 7)

Comment: You have two completely separate wiring systems in your house.  One is dangerous mains voltage and is completely inside the boxes (the ones you keep taking lids off against my advice).  The other system is safe 24V and is completely outside the boxes, tied to those "24V/25V" terminals on the transformers.  **This separation is deliberate**.  Low voltage is used for thermostats, doorbells, and furnace controls, and your Nest must be attached to that 24V system only, **as its instructions *clearly* say**. You have done nothing to explore your 24V system, and cannot advise further without that.

Comment: @Harper, I have not opened the lid after I took the picture. Sorry if my words make you feel so. The reason I asked if I can just connect to the yellow cap bundle, because the red wire is coming down anyway. Maybe this make you feel so?So you advice is to elongate the unused red wire all the way to the terminal of second transformer, and connect it to one of the terminal? If so, then I have to open the first box again. I will also take another look at the wiring inside the second transformer again.

Comment: It looks as though you have a vintage 1950's boiler not a furnace. Most modern furnaces do not have a separate transformer for control voltages they have a built in transformer and circuit board. That is probably why you couldn't find the circuit board, there isn't one. The controls are all high voltage and you shouldn't be in those boxes. The thermostat wire will most likely be a dark brown cable taped or zip-tied to the outside of a conduit until it gets to the transformer and low voltage side of the control box.

Comment: @ArchonOSX, thank you for your response. It's a very old system, that's why I have real hard time finding where to connect the common wire, since most online guide have a circuit board with C terminal. The transformer does have a 25v terminal, I forgot to include the cover after I cleaned up the article. I have updated the picture of transformer (picture 6).

Comment: It appears as though they used #14 gauge wire on the secondary side of the transformer. And went back into the J-box with it. They must have made joints somewhere with the smaller gauge wire for the thermosatat. These two wires provide 25v AC for low voltage control. Really old thermostats were nothing more than switches and only needed to complete the circuit between two wires. For the Nest you need the two wires from the transformer to power the Nest all the time and a control wire to call for heat when you want it. It will be up to you do figure out how your old system can be adapted.

Comment: @ArchonOSX, I am a newbie in the electrical circuit stuff. The other solution I saw online is to 24 VAC wall plug-in transformer, and split it at the end of the cord and plug it into the Rc and C on thermostat.  Would it be a better option than trying to fiddle with the wires mess on the boiler? I was hoping someone can help me identify where to hook up the common wire, so I don't have to buy another transformer.

Comment: The thermostat works by completing a circuit. If you have a separate transformer then you can't complete the low voltage circuit for the thermostat to work. Get yourself a couple sets of rechargeable batteries and a charger for the stat or call a reputable electrician to sort this out. Honestly I don't think these "smart" thermostats are worth all this trouble.